# Using superclass methods as instance methods

Tags: python, inheritance, class-method, instance-methods

I am currently reading through Luciano Ramalho's excellent book [Fluent Python](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/22800567). In a chapter about interfaces and inheritance we build a subclass of a list (see [github](https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code-2e/blob/master/13-protocol-abc/tombolist.py) for the original code) and I am confused about the way we define one of the instance methods. For a simlified example my confusion is caused by a situation as follows:

```
class ListWithLoadMethod(list):
    load = list.extend
```

which generates a new subclass of list which has an alias for the `extend` method as `load`. We can test the class by writing

```
loaded_list = ListWithLoadMethod(range(4))
print(loaded_list)
loaded_list.extend(range(3))
print(loaded_list)
loaded_list.load(range(3))
print(loaded_list)
```

which produces, as expected:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

My confusion arises from on the difference of class methods and static methods. When the new instance of `ListWithLoadedMethod` is created, it is a subclass of `list`, but when we initialize the instance we point `load` to `list.extend`; how does Python know that by `list.extend` we do not mean that `load` should point to a class method of the `list` class but to actually (apparently?) inherit the instance method of the superclass list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually not inheriting from superclass (list), but creating reference to `list.extend` method

When you inspect their identity, you will see that they are same objects in memory.

```
id(list.extend)
Out: 3102044666032

id(ListWithLoadMethod.load)
Out: 3102044666032
```

Comment: Thanks! I have to remember the id function from now on ^^

So, to extend my question if you don't mind: what happens when an instance of ListWithLoadMethod calls list.extend? Does list.extend(iterable) actually look like list.extend(self, iterable) when in use or what?

Comment: When you call list.extend on instance of ListWithLoadMethod below happens: 1) l_obj = ListWithLoadMethod() 2) ListWithLoadMethod.extend(l_obj, iterable). So it works similar other class methods

Comment: Thanks again! You've been a great help.